# In SPSS, Loop within a Do repeat

Tags: loops, spss

While doing data management in SPSS I´m trying to see if an individual was on sick leave on any given day, 1 to 365 days from an index date. Thus, if the individual is on sick leave on any of these dates i want a "1" in a variable corresponding to that day (v1-v365). I have tried different applications of the `LOOP`- and `Do Repeat`-command, but have to realize I don´t fully understand the logic behind it.

Data:

'''

```
data list list / ID(F2) Index(F11) Start_Sick(F11) End_Sick(F11).

BEGIN DATA.

1, 13808188800, 13770777600, 13839125500

2, 13837564800, 13705811200, 13839020000

3, 13807497600, 13847548800, 13855017600

4, 13841107200, 13839120000, 13855017600

5, 13830307200, 13847068800, 13855017600

end data.

dataset name MyData WINDOW=FRONT.

Formats Index Start_Sick End_Sick(date11).

VARIABLE LABELS Start_Sick 'Start of a sick leave period'.

VARIABLE LABELS End_Sick 'End of a sick leave period'.

VARIABLE LABELS Index 'Index date'.
```

'''
My non working solution:
'''

```
VECTOR v(365).

do repeat t = v1 to v365

 /v = v1 to v365.

LOOP cnt=1 TO 365 by 1.

IF Start_Sick LE datesum(Index,cnt,'days') and End_Sick GE datesum(Index,cnt,'days') t = 1.

END LOOP.

end repeat.

    EXECUTE.
```

'''
When running i get either '1' in all of v1 to v365 for a case or all are missing. Am I using the wrong tools or am I using the tool wrongly?

Best wishes,
Björn

Comment: you can use nested `loop`, instead of `loop` inside a `do repeat`. Do repeat is not loop inside a loop; do repeat goes iteratively through each pair of iterators

Comment: Nice first question (+1 for data list example)! Welcome to Stack-Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the `loop` - the `do repeat` here is redundent.
This is your own code, cleaned of the `do repeat` part and with a bit of adjustments - seems to work fine:

```
VECTOR v(365).
LOOP #cnt=1 TO 365 by 1.
IF Start_Sick LE datesum(Index,#cnt,'days') and End_Sick GE datesum(Index,#cnt,'days') v(#cnt) = 1.
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Thank you eli-k! Your code suggestion worked in my full dataset as well. This use of '#' will be very useful in the future.

Comment: BTW the addition of '#' to the variable name is just so it won't appear later in the dataset after you've finished using it, but the code would work just as well with a regular variable too.